# Azure Paas + SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

Hi I am planning to move my SharePoint Application database from SharePoint List to SQL Azure. I am planning to create an API for that so I could Access my Data using Angular to that API. But I have a question is there a way to make sure that the API I will be create can and only be access inside my O365 SharePoint? Is there a way to build some kind of trust or authentication? What are the security features I could use to make my data safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are bunch of security features like: 
Securing APIs with key, JSON Web Token (JWT) validation, and IP filtering.
I think you could use IP [Filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) for your scenario.